# [Path Analyzer](ApiContainer.RegisterType) : sitecore error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

Running Sitecore 8.2 throwing some error as per below, I have disabled all the Sitecore.PathAnalyzer configs on CD, and I'm not able to figure out where it's getting exec from

**Diabled Configs on CD**

> Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Client.config Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.config.disabled
>   -Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.config.disabled
>   -Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config.disabled
>   -Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services.config.disabled
>   -Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services.RemoteServer.config.disabled
>   -Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.StorageProviders.config.disabled

**Error**

> WARN  Path Analyzer Registering
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Contracts.ITreeManager type with ApiContainer
>   failed, Config entry pathAnalyzer/treeManager doesn't exist
>
> FATAL Path Analyzer Can't create instance
>   using path ''. Make sure the referred element is present in
>   configuration

Comment: Maybe related: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/766858

Comment: Can you check if 
Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config file is enabled on your solution?

Comment: ive disabled all the Sitecore.PathAnalyzer configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue by removing below dll's from CD, its genuine bug from sitecore

```
Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.dll
Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Client.dll
Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services.dll
Sitecore.SequenceAnalyzer.dll
```